# How to check the type of a postgresql dump file

Tags: postgresql

Suppose you were given a postgresql dump file, not knowing if it is a script file or archive file, how would you check the type of the file?

I would like to know this because this has to do with the issue what command to use on restoring the dump file.

The pgsql version used is 9.6.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, you could use the `file` command to determine if it is a plain text file or not.

But I would use `pg_restore -l dumpfile`: if you get an error, it is a plain format dump.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked well and is easy to use.